# Declaring instance variables for an Objective C interface in the .m file (in release mode)

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, cocoa

I can build the following code for debug, but not for release for an OS X target in xcode:

myclass.h:

```
@interface myclass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;

@end
```

myclass.m:

```
@implementation myclass {
    NSString *_name;
}

@synthesize name = _name;

@end
```

Any ideas why? On iOS it builds for both release and debug.

I understand that moving the instance variable declaration to the .h will work, but my intention is to hide the implementation details (of course the real class is more complex than this example). I've tried this on the latest xcode version (4.6, build 4H127) on Mountain Lion when building 64-bit apps.

Comment: 1. What's the error? 2. Why declare the instance variable at all when that `@synthesize` will do it for you?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Sorry, it was a typo (not a crap). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @jkcl: Why dont you use copy-paste feature, that will save your time and no type error atleast in the codes. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use a class extension.  In your `.m` file, write

```
@interface myclass ()
{
    NSString *_name;
}
@end
```

above your `@implementation` for `myclass`.

On the other hand, you don't actually need to declare the instance variable which is backing your property.  If you just write

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
```

in your class declaration (the code beginning with `@interface myclass : NSObject` and ending with `@end`), a backing `NSString *` ivar `_name` will be generated for you automatically, and you'll be able to access this ivar inside the instance methods of `myclass`.  You don't even need to write `@synthesize name = _name;`.  Furthermore, if you want to use a variable name other than `_name` to back your property `name`, you needn't declare the ivar; instead you can just use `@synthesize`

```
@synthesize name = m_Name;
```

inside your class' `@implementation` block.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Didn't realise that `_` ivars get generated automatically with `@synthesize`. Rather cool.

NB: Your last point was a typo on my part. Amazing that even those who didn't know the answer like you did, managed to point that out vociferously:)

Comment: Yeah, it's really nice not having to explicitly write down ivars anymore.  Keep in mind, though, that you don't even need to use `@synthesize`!  If you just write `@property int foo;` in your class declaration, a backing ivar `_foo` will be created for you--without `@synthesize`.  (There is an exception: if you override both the setter and the getter for your property, a backing ivar will no longer be generated.)

Comment: Thanks again; that's even better. Also good to know that if I use custom setters/getters (I occasionally do), this won't work. BTW, the answer by @BenedictCohen below is worth noting as the code above had different behaviours for debug and release.

Comment: @NateChandler The first part of your answer is only one option. There is nothing wrong with declaring instance variables in the `@implementation` block. You don't need to create a class extension just for this.

Answer (score 3):

Instance variables in the implementation block requires the modern Objective-C runtime. See [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html). It could be that the release is targeting a  version of OS X which does not support the modern runtime.

Comment: I suspect that your answer is quite relevant in that my code was failing to build on release only. I've up-voted, but will take the other answer for now (sorry) as I learnt something new and it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

you have not specified object type of the property "`name`"  here:

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) name;
```

use this

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
```

Comment: That was a typo. I've fixed in the original post.